# IE9 CSS3 support

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I've made a website with some css3 styles like transitions, border-radius, box-shadow and text-shadow.

I have a current version of IE9 and it all looks fine.

However, I have another computer which has IE9 but it's not been updated recently. On this one, either the CSS3 styles don't appear, which actually breaks the page, or I can make it default to the IE8/ IE7 stylesheet, which works but ain't so pretty.

This is a bit worrying as I'm guessing the general IE9 user isn't that rigorous about keeping their browser up to date.

Is there a solution to this? Or is it simply that I have to wait for people to update? Can I put message on the site which will detect old versions of IE9 and tell them to update? Or do it need to make an IE9 specific stylesheet?

I don't really want to put my site up here but I can PM you a link if you like.

Thanks

Comment: What version is the IE9 that doesn't display properly in it? Is it a beta version?

Comment: They are both showing in this version: 9.0.8112.16421 However the Product ID in the one that works is: 03553-997-8617616-27675. The Product ID in the one that doesn't display properly is this: 03553-032-2927503-85002. The version that's not displaying well is in need of updating (we don't use that computer much) but we would rather keep it how it is and find out what the problem is incase it's affecting other users of the website. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Needed more room so I am answering here instead of a comment.

Since they have the same version number (9.0.8112.16421), they are both the same. Your problem is probably elsewhere and while I'm not certain how it renders CSS3 effects, IE9 uses DirectX to use Direct2D and DirectWrite.

Check to see the capabilities of the computer having the issue and see if it's properly using DirectX.

Also try some other computers since I suspect that issue is related to that computer only. If your code works on one computer, it'll probably work on them all that don't have issues.

Comment: Thanks - definitely some stuff to investigate there. I'll post my findings.